# how to integrate a invoice with API keys in nowpayments wallet?

Tags: curl, payment

I have a HTML website with products, and I want to sell them, so as I don't have the backend of my website, I would like to add just the button of payment, so the customers so can pay and after successful payment see their downloadable dropbox link, or redirect them to that link

I saw this code in nowpayments documentations, but I don't quite understand where and how should I add this code, so the customers can see the button

I understand that for every product I should create a new button with different price and different redirect URL.

Can anyone help me with the task?

```
curl --location 'https://api.nowpayments.io/v1/invoice' \
--header 'x-api-key: {{api-key}}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "price_amount": 1000,
  "price_currency": "usd",
  "order_id": "RGDBP-21314",
  "order_description": "Apple Macbook Pro 2019 x 1",
  "ipn_callback_url": "https://nowpayments.io",
  "success_url": "https://nowpayments.io",
  "cancel_url": "https://nowpayments.io"
}
'
```